# How to match a character to find if it is a special character in javascript

Tags: javascript, automation

I am trying to find whether my string contains any special character. I am very new to javascript and would really appreciate your help.

Here is a simplified code :

```
function checkMe(text){
    var reg = '/[a-zA-Z0-9-]/gi';
    var character = text.charAt(0);
    if((character.match(reg)) == false){
        alert("special character found!!  ");
     }
}
```

This is not giving desired output. Please help!!

Comment: What do you mean by "special character"?

Comment: Exactly my question as well :)

Comment: HI! Here is a function, which returns true if string matches regular expression, and false if not:

    (/\your_regex/).test("your string to test") // true | false

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a regular expression and not a string with a regular expression inside.

Then you need just to check, because, you get for a single valid character an array with the matched character. If no match occurs, then [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns `null`.

```js
function checkMe(text) {
    var reg = /[a-z0-9-]/gi;   // regular expr, A-Z is not necessary, because of flag i
    if (!text[0].match(reg)) { // test for falsyness
        console.log("special character found!");
    }
}

checkMe('Übermut');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean special characters mean `!@#` etc.
Here is how you can check by calling `test` on regular expression.
See the code below, one with special chars and one with normal chars.

```js
function checkMe(text) {
  var reg = /[a-zA-Z0-9-]/gi;
  var character = text.charAt(0);
  if (!reg.test(character)) {
    alert("special character found!!  ");
  } else {
    alert("NO special character found!!  ");
  }
}


checkMe('!@#$');
checkMe('normal');
```